# How can I get a default font name of label control?

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I need to get the default font-name of text from a label control. (i.e)

```
<asp:Label Text="Test" ID="lblq" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

How to find the font-name (or) font-family of the Label 'lblq' ? and Is font-family depends on the browser?

I have loaded default fonts in a dropdownlist. when I click a button, I just need to set the label 'lblq' font-name into selected value of dropdownlist.

Comment: You could use javascript / jquery to get a css property. It is not asp but an opportunity. Is it necessary to use asp?

Comment: @Taz I edited my question. Read twice before you give downvote.

Answer (score 1):

Try:-

```
string myVal = lblq.Font.Name;
```

Comment: 'myVal' always returns empty.

Answer (score 0):

this is not as relavent to your question but might give you a head start

```
            // this will give you the list of all installed fonts
             using System.Drawing.Text;

            InstalledFontCollection fontList = new InstalledFontCollection();  
            foreach(FontFamily family in fontList.Families)  
            {  
                ListBox1.Items.Add(family.Name);  
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find original font name using following code:

```
string originalFontName=lblq.Font.OriginalFontName;
```